# Javascript Regex match k that is not followed by a number 0

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match ever `k` that is not followed by a number `0`.

For example `k0` is not valid while `k1` is.

Comment: Try a character class `k[1-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
const regex = /k(?!0).*/g

console.log('k0k1k2'.match(regex))
```

without  .*  to get just a element k, like this

```js
const regex = /k(?!0)/g

console.log('k0k1k2'.match(regex))
```

Comment: why is g flag needed?

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili, g is for global search, .* to get element after k, it's  generate pattern to get more element after k  ,  for exmaple "console.log('k0k1k2dddd'.match(regex))" the result is k1k2dddd

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili, I do for a general case

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili, your example assert("k1".match('/k(?!0)/g')[1] == "k") , you should remove the signle quote ('/k(?!0)/g') in regex expression, so you code will be match(/k(?!0)/g)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all 'k' and number (but not k0) and dive into all matches like this:

```
var s = 'k0k10k2000dasdasdasdk1k0'
var re = /k[1-9]\d*/g;
var m;
while (m = re.exec(s)) {
  console.log(m);
}

// [ 'k10', index: 2, input: 'k0k10k2000dasdasdasdk1k0' ]
// [ 'k2000', index: 5, input: 'k0k10k2000dasdasdasdk1k0' ]
// [ 'k1', index: 20, input: 'k0k10k2000dasdasdasdk1k0' ]
```